# How to move Gnome notifications

Tags: command-line, gnome, 18.04, gnome-shell, notification

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. As a unity user I am facing a big difference with gnome as notifications are showed up at the top center. It is annoying while dealing with specially browser tabs. I searched the Internet and found [this](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/03/choose-gnome-notifications-appear), but it did not work as described. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Could you expand a bit more on "*did not work as described*"? At which step is it failing (extension installation issue or installs fine, but doesn't work or something else)? That extension works fine for me.

Comment: @pomsky Installation seems OK with no errors, but I cannot find it in gnome tweak tool.. Am I wrong?

Comment: @pomsky yes, it does not show up..

Comment: @pomsky it says "GNOME Shell Extensions cannot list your installed extensions."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77392/discussion-between-nuwan-thisara-and-pomsky).

Comment: Just curious why rather than struggling with Gnome's differences over Unity you don't just use Unity in the first place? That's what I did in 18.04  until I'm ready to learn Gnome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To install the [Panel OSD](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/708/panel-osd/) extension (as suggested in the external link you've mentioned) properly first install the `chrome-gnome-shell` by running

```
sudo apt install chrome-gnome-shell
```

Then go https://extensions.gnome.org/ using Firefox or Google Chrome. The webpage should ask you to install a browser add-on/extension, install it.

Then go to the [extension's webpage](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/708/panel-osd/). You'll find a toggle button. Turn it on.

Once the installation is finished, you'll be able to change the preferences of the extension using *(GNOME) Tweaks*.